# Receiving XML postbacks

Tags: php, xml

I'm a pretty seasoned PHP developer, and have integrated APIs before with platforms like PayPal and Authorize.Net after finding classes to work with... It's just that now I have to implement with limelight network's API and I have to start from scratch... Here's what I want to do after receiving a callback, posted to a PHP page I make:

Grab the XML in its raw form and send it to myself in an email so I can analyze what I'm working with.

No code yet, just an email function... the question is: how can I extract the XML from the post?  I'm sure I would need to make a handler, but I'm not certain where to start. Please advise.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your server configuration, you can usually get raw posted XML either from $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA global or from file_get_contents('php://input');. I am not going to bother a seasoned PHP developer with the details of how to email something;)